# How to fix a div (or a panel...) after some scroll (in GWT)?

Tags: gwt, panel

I am trying to achieve this effect : http://massless.org/pegs/
You can see that after scrolling, the left navigation bar stay fixed on the top of the page.

How could I achieve a such effect with GWT ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there are really two ways of doing this. Both are based of of the knowledge that GWT is really just Javascript in the end.

1. Since this is an effect, not really pertaining to functionality, you could wire this up in an external js file and just use Pegs as is.
2. Duplicate the functionality in GWT.

   a. (Widget).getElement().getStyle().setTop("33px");

   b. http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/  =  Use this module and just introspect the Pegs extension.

You shouldn't have to touch JSNI (which is good).

Personally I would go with the first one if possible. Option two is based on window onscroll, and depending on the situation, that can get really, really slow.

Comment: Hello ProtoWeapon, ok, what happen is that to have a fast initial load time, I would like to avoid external lib, such as JQuerry (gwt-jquerry too...). Is it a good idea ?

Comment: I have not seen adding a few libraries make a dent in load times. SmartGWT is massive, so that does matter, but most (gwt-jquery, cellwidgets, etc) I have not noticed a lag at all. However, if your experience proves otherwise, 2a. does not require an external library. Just add an onscroll even onto the Window object and alter the style. Sometimes this is sufficient, sometimes I desert the solution altogether due to lag.

Comment: As far as just using jquery, I would not worry about it. This still looks like the best solution, and if you use the google jquery import, chances are your clients browser already has it cached. And if not, the average consumer still wouldn't notice.